# How can I register my service in double projects?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, grpc

I have a gRPC and API controller projects in one solution.
When I want to register a service in both projects got this error:

> 'Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: SmsPanel.SendServiceCore.Interfaces.ICreditService Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: SmsPanel.SendServiceCore.Services.CreditService': Unable to resolve service for type 'SmsPanel.SendServiceCore.Interfaces.ICoreService' while attempting to activate 'SmsPanel.SendServiceCore.Services.CreditService'.)'

This is my API **program.cs**:

```
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ISmsPanelContext, SmsPanelContext>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IUserRepository, EFUserRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ISmsInOutBoxService, SmsInOutBoxService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ISettingRepository, EFSettingRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ITransactionRepository, EFTransactionRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ISMSInOutBoxDetailRepository, EFSMSInOutBoxDetailRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ISmsInOutBoxRepository, EFSMSInOutBoxRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ICorrespondingSendRepository, EFCorrespondingSendRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IUserLineRepository, EFUserLineRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ISMSLineRepository, EFSMSLineRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ITemplateRepository, EFTemplateRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ISMSRouteRepository, EFSMSRouteRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ITariffPriceRepository, EFTariffPriceRepository>();

builder.Services.AddScoped<ICoreService, CoreService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ICreditService, CreditService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IDeliveryService, DeliveryService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IMessageService, MessageService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<INumbersService, NumbersService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ISendSmsService, SendSmsService>();

builder.Services.AddScoped<ISMSInvalidWordRepository, EFSMSInvalidWordRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ISpecialListRepository, EFSpecialListRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IIntelligentSendRepository, EFIntelligentSendRepository>();
```

This is my gRPC **program.cs**:

```
builder.Services.AddGrpc(options =>
{
    options.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
    options.Interceptors.Add<ExceptionInterceptor>();
});

builder.Services.AddGrpcReflection(); // Grpc.AspNetCore.Server.Reflection
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

builder.Services.AddScoped<ICreditService, CreditService>();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it, I should register other services in gRPC too.

Answer (score 1):

You need to register all the required services in the `gRPC` project too. In this particular case - at least `builder.Services.AddScoped<ICoreService, CoreService>();`, but I would guess that some more will be required.

Quite often this is handled by introducing some helper shared between the projects:

```cs
public static class RegistrationExts
{
    public static IServiceCollection RegisterServices(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddScoped<ICreditService, CreditService>();
        services.AddScoped<ICoreService, CoreService>();
        // ...  the rest of shared registrations
        return services;
    }
}
```

And then call it in both projects -> `builder.Services.RegisterServices()`.

Also you can introduce several such methods based on layers/features separation.